# How to install next.js on windows 7

Tags: reactjs, node.js, next.js

I am trying to install next.js but not able to install on windows 7 , i tried different version of node.
suggest me right way how to install. is it possible without command.

Answer (score -2):

For install Next.js on Windows 7, you can follow these steps

1. **Install Node.js**: First, you need to have Node.js installed on your system. You can download the installer from the official Node.js website (https://nodejs.org/) and follow the installation instructions. Make sure to install the LTS version, which is recommended for most users.
2. **Open Command Prompt**: Once Node.js is installed, open the Command Prompt by pressing `Win + R`, typing `cmd`, and hitting Enter.
3. **Create a New Next.js Project**: In the Command Prompt, navigate to the directory where you want to create your Next.js project using the `cd` command. For example:

   ```
   cd path\to\desired\directory
   ```
4. **Initialize a New Next.js Project**: Once you're in the desired directory, you can initialize a new Next.js project using the following command:

   ```
   npx create-next-app my-next-app
   ```

   Replace `my-next-app` with the name you want for your project.
5. **Navigate to the Project Directory**: After the project is created, navigate into the project directory:

   ```
   cd my-next-app
   ```
6. **Start the Development Server**: Once inside the project directory, you can start the development server by running:

   ```
   npm run dev
   ```

   This command will start the Next.js development server, and you can access your Next.js application by opening a web browser and navigating to `http://localhost:3000`.

Comment: thank you but, https://nodejs.org/  not able install , it showing minimum version 8 windows

Comment: @MAYURSANCHETI please follow this documentation 
https://www.centennialsoftwaresolutions.com/post/install-node-js-on-windows-7

Comment: Did you create this answer with [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1)?

Comment: this link not helpful , node install is ok, what about next.js on windows 7

Comment: @DarkBee, I believe this content is copied from a web post. Could you please clarify if you have a solution to share, or if you're inquiring about something specific?

Comment: So you plagiarized content without attribution?

Comment: I apologize for any misunderstanding. Could you please provide more context or details about the content in question? I'd be happy to address any concerns you may have.

Comment: @DarkBee why you down my answer. do you have try with solution ? directly put down without checking actuall issue.

Comment: Not sure what more I need to address, any form of using [ChatGPT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vKeB.png) to create content on this website is [banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1) and if you indeed copied this from another source without any attribution then you are just plagiarizing which is, for obvious reason, also not allowed

Comment: No I don't understand, especially not when you are making "threats", please have a look at the following [article](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268630/446594) which answers all you need to know about plagiarized content - [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)